# Canvas - move image-problem

Tags: html, canvas, svg

i have a problem with my script that use canvas.

I want to move my image but with drawImage the image moves but the result is something like that:

[image]

so, my code is

```
function desenhaBonecoDir(){
    var ctxt = document.getElementById('camadaBoneco').getContext("2d");
    bonecoX = bonecoX -10;
    ctxt.drawImage(bonecoLeft, bonecoX, bonecoY);

}
```

and i think that the only way is using SVG (retained mode). It is correct?

Any tutorial? or example? - "how moving an image with SVG"
How i can solve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solves my problem

```
context2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Good example here: http://brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/38744.aspx?p=3

Answer (score 2):

You need to erase all or part of your canvas and redraw. Yes, using SVG or HTML + CSS is easier, but not necessary.

Here's an example of moving sprites over a background, with the option to erase and redraw all or part of the BG: http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_sprites_canvas.html

Note that just using CSS is [faster than canvas](http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_speed.html).