# How to move only one image on canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I have about 10 images I draw on canvas in html5. Then, I would like to move the first image only, the other one should remain in place. here is the code :

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 375);
ctx.translate(20, 0);
```

I understand that I move the whole canvas with that code... but how to move only one image not the whole canvas... I think about using two canvas... but look like a bad solution to me !...

i guest the save and restore will be used, but when i try, it repeat the images... not good !. i am kind of lost, and read a lot of tutorial and read that : [Canvas - move image-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183872/canvas-move-image-problem) but not usefull. HELP

Comment: Editing your question is the wrong way to signify you've found the answer; either delete your question or put it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: base on that answer i manage to make it work 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496674/how-to-rotate-one-image-in-a-canvas

Comment: Put it as an *answer*. Then you can accept it.

Comment: Proper answer, that mostly answer my own question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496674/how-to-rotate-one-image-in-a-canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final working code

```
function drawOnCanvas() {

    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 375);

    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

    ctx.translate(image_objects[0].width/2, image_objects[0].height/2);
    ctx.scale(scale,scale);
    ctx.translate(-image_objects[0].width/2, -image_objects[0].height/2);

    ctx.translate(image_objects[0].width/2, image_objects[0].height/2);
    ctx.rotate(rotate); 
    ctx.translate(-image_objects[0].width/2, -image_objects[0].height/2);

    ctx.translate(movex, movey);
    ctx.drawImage(image_objects[0],0,0);

    ctx.restore();  

    if (hide_images == false) {
        for (var i = 1; i < image_objects.length; ++i) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = opacity;
        ctx.drawImage(image_objects[i], 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```